# View not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using **Return File()** method to download file in razor pages and on successful download of the file; the view is not updating as i have to show success message on file download. Is there any solution, so i can download file using return File() method and show/hide div on bool variable.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGenerateReport()
    {
        DisplayPage = true;
        
        ReportsDataModel data = new ReportsDataModel
        {
            ReportType = ReportType,
            StartDate = StartDateTime
        };

        var reportModelList = await _manager.GetReports(data);

        var cc = new CsvConfiguration(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream: ms, encoding: new UTF8Encoding(true)))
            {
                using (var cw = new CsvWriter(sw, cc))
                {
                    cw.WriteRecords(reportModelList);
                }
                //await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("atlas.interop.saveAsFile", Model.ReportType + DateTime.Now.Date + ".xlsx", ms.ToArray());
                DisplayPage = false;
                return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", string.Concat(ReportModel.ReportType, StartDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"), ".csv"));
            }
        }

        return Page();
        
    }
<div class="fourPnl">
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="GenerateReport">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ReportType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="reportType" asp-for="@Model.ReportType" class="form-control p-0">
                    <option value="">--Select Report Type--</option>
                    <option value="UserActivityReport" selected>User Activity Report</option>
                    @*<option value="TicketReport">Ticket Report</option>*@
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.StartDateTime" class="control-label"></label>
            @*<select type="datetime" asp-for="@Model.ReportModel.StartDate" class="form-control" />*@
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.StartDateTime" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" />
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:25px">
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" class="btn btn-primary mb-1" />
        </div>
        if (Model.DisplayPage)
        {
            <Loading />
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="toast">
                <div class="toast-header">
                    Result
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body">
                    Report Downloaded Successfully.
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This would not work.  When you start a file downloading the response cannot be updated.  Here you have few options one of which is to use Javascript to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ajax to call handler:

handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGenerateReport()
    {
        DisplayPage = true;
        
        ReportsDataModel data = new ReportsDataModel
        {
            ReportType = ReportType,
            StartDate = StartDateTime
        };

        var reportModelList = await _manager.GetReports(data);

        var cc = new CsvConfiguration(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream: ms, encoding: new UTF8Encoding(true)))
            {
                using (var cw = new CsvWriter(sw, cc))
                {
                    cw.WriteRecords(reportModelList);
                }
                //await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("atlas.interop.saveAsFile", Model.ReportType + DateTime.Now.Date + ".xlsx", ms.ToArray());
                DisplayPage = false;
                return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", string.Concat(ReportModel.ReportType, StartDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"), ".csv"));
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult("error");
        
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="fourPnl">
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="GenerateReport">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ReportType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="reportType" asp-for="@Model.ReportType" class="form-control p-0">
                    <option value="">--Select Report Type--</option>
                    <option value="UserActivityReport" selected>User Activity Report</option>
                    @*<option value="TicketReport">Ticket Report</option>*@
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.StartDateTime" class="control-label"></label>
            @*<select type="datetime" asp-for="@Model.ReportModel.StartDate" class="form-control" />*@
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.StartDateTime" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" />
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:25px">
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" class="btn btn-primary mb-1" onclick="postformdata()" />
        </div>
        <div id="DisplayPage">

        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

js:

```
function postformdata() {
            event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=GenerateReport',
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: { ReportType: $("#ReportType").val(), StartDateTime:$("#StartDateTime").val()},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "error") {
                    document.getElementById("DisplayPage").innerHTML  = '<div class="toast"><div class="toast-header">Result</div><div class="toast-body">Report Downloaded Successfully.</div></div>';
                }
                else { 
                    document.getElementById("DisplayPage").innerHTML  = '<Loading />';
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        })
        }
```